# How do I get my Discord Bot to send a message as if using the print function in python?

Tags: python, discord, io, event-handling, bots

I'm using python to code my first Discord bot, and I'm still getting used to how the async works. From what I can tell, it needs a triggering event, such as receiving a message, in order to be activated. However, I want to be able to just print messages to the discord chat as if using the print() method, and request for input as needed like using input()

I've managed to get an initial Cog for my game set up like this

```
class Game(commands.Cog, name="Ruby Palace"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.playing = False
        self.player_character = None
        self.battle = None

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx):
        await ctx.channel.send('Would you like to play a game?')
        msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message")
        if cm.y_n(msg):
            await ctx.channel.send("Alright! Let's get started!")
            self.playing = True

            #i wanna change this next part so I can just call methods that will handle this job and make the process cleaner and compartmentalized

            await ctx.channel.send("What class would you like to play? Fighter/Rogue/Mage")
            player_class = await self.bot.wait_for("message")
            await ctx.channel.send("What is your character's name?")
            name = await self.bot.wait_for("message")
            self.create_character(player_class.content, name.content)
            await ctx.channel.send(f"Congratulations! {self.player_character} has been created!")
            self.start_battle()
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send('uh-oh')
    def create_character(self, p_class, name):
        self.player_character = p_class(name)
 

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Game(bot))
```

However, I want to be able to do something closer to this

```
import os
from abilities import *
from random import randint
from discord.ext import commands
import global_cmds as cm
import units
enemy1 = Unit("Ted")
enemy2 = Unit("")
class Game(commands.Cog, name="Ruby Palace"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.playing = False
        self.player_character = None
        self.battle = None


    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx):
        await ctx.channel.send('Would you like to play a game?')
        msg = await self.bot.wait_for("message")
        if cm.y_n(msg):
            await ctx.channel.send("Alright! Let's get started!")
            self.playing = True
            
            # if i can do it this way, i can add new code and adjust existing code more easily, but I can't figure out how to do it

            self.create_character()
        else:
            await ctx.channel.send('uh-oh')
    def create_character(self):
        send "What class"
        class = response
        send "what's the name"
        name = response
        self.player_character = class(name)
    
    
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Game(bot))
```

Comment: What do you mean by _I want to be able to just print messages to the discord chat as if using the print() method_ ? Isn't it already what you're doing with `ctx.send` ?

Comment: but ctx.send requires async, and from what i can tell async functions can't be called normally

Comment: Then can you be more precise about what you want to do, in comparison to what you're doing currently ? What does "calling normally" mean ? Is there an _abnormal_ way to call things ?

Comment: yes, normally you call a function by invoking it, such as print("print this"), but with the async it waits for an event to happen, such as recieving a command or message and the processes, instead of just being invoked within the code manually